# crypto.privateDecrypt works on windows but not in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, windows, ubuntu-16.04, cryptojs

I have a code that reads a privateKey ( which is in PEM format ) and an encrypted text that I want to decrypt it. When I run the code in windows everything is working and it decrypt the text by

```
let buffer = Buffer.from(encryptedData,'base64');
crypto.privateDecrypt(privatekey, buffer);
```

However when I run the same code in Ubuntu I receive the following error :

```
"'Passphrase required for encrypted key.TypeError: Passphrase ' +
  'required for encrypted key    at Object.privateDecrypt ' +
  '(internal/crypto/cipher.js:53:12)    at e1c2 ' +...
```

"

I used console.log(encryptedData,privatekey,buffer) in both windows and Ubuntu system and they are identical. Also in privatekey I did not use passphrase. 
anyone has idea why in Ubuntu I get such error and in windows it is working fine? Could it be related to privatekey format that is actually .pam format and due to whitespaces linux could not handle it?

EDIT:

My private key has this format

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJrTBXBgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wSjApBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwHAQIdq79fP1MZogCAggA
MAwGCCqGSIb3DQIJBQAwHQYJYIZIAWUDBAEqBBDMX/L46fPKcSQkgXrwpLtqBIIJ
..
```

I basically generated it via

```
crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
    modulusLength: 4096,
    publicKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'spki',
      format: 'pem'
    },
    privateKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'pkcs8',
      format: 'pem',
      cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',
      passphrase: ''
    }
  });
```

When I check more in internet I saw an example at [enter link description here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22792)
that the header of the private key is "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" and actually I could run that code in Ubuntu and no error happens. So  it looks the problem is related to the header that change due to 'pkcs8' type inside privateKeyEncoding. 
Also I noticed that my node version on windows is 10.15.3 and on ubuntu is 12.4
Could it be also related to the node version change?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried something very similar on both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. In my case I generate public / private key files, encrypt then decrypt using these. It's working well on both platforms. It's worth giving this a go to see if it works for you. Node versions are: Windows: 10.15 Ubuntu 10.16.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require("fs");

function generateKeyFiles() {

    const keyPair = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
        modulusLength: 4096,
        publicKeyEncoding: {
            type: 'spki',
            format: 'pem'
        },
        privateKeyEncoding: {
        type: 'pkcs8',
        format: 'pem',
        cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',
        passphrase: ''
        }
    });

    fs.writeFileSync("public_key", keyPair.publicKey);
    fs.writeFileSync("private_key", keyPair.privateKey);
}

// Encrypt a string given a public key file. Encode the result in base64.
function encryptString (plaintext, publicKeyFile) {
    const publicKey = fs.readFileSync(publicKeyFile, "utf8");
    const encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, Buffer.from(plaintext));
    return encrypted.toString("base64");
}

// Encrypt a string given a cipherText (in base64) and a private key file.
function decryptString (ciphertext, privateKeyFile) {
    const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(privateKeyFile, "utf8");
    const decrypted = crypto.privateDecrypt(privateKey, Buffer.from(ciphertext, "base64"));
    return decrypted.toString("utf8");
}

generateKeyFiles();

const plainText = "I have spread my dreams under your feet. Tread softly because you tread on my dreams.";

const cipherText = encryptString(plainText, "./public_key");

console.log();
console.log("Plaintext:", plainText);
console.log();
console.log("Ciphertext: ", cipherText);
console.log();
console.log("Decrypted Text: ", decryptString(cipherText, "private_key"));
console.log();
```

You could also try copying the key files from Windows to Ubuntu (skipping the generate key files step). This is working for me too.

Comment: Thanks Terry. I just changed the installed node in Ubuntu to LTS version so I could not test it for now.